# OpenGL - Moving with arrow key through objects

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to create a matrix with 9 squares on OpenGL 1.0  and firstly the center square to be active and. After that to move through them with arrow keys. I created the squares with two for loops and added a function "activeElement" to change the color of the active element. This code compiles but it is not what I want. I don't know where is the problem.
Thanks :)

```
#include<SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
int px;
int py;


void activeElement(int px,int py, int x, int y)
{
    if( px == x && py == y){
        glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    }else{glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);}
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45,640.0/480.0,1.0,500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}





void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-20.0);


    for(int i=-1; i<=1; i++){
        for(int j=-1; j<=1 ;j++){

        glPushMatrix();
        activeElement(px, py, i,j);
        glTranslatef(4*i,4*j,0.0);
         glScalef(2.0,2.0,2.0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f( 0.0, 1.0, -8.0);
        glVertex3f( -1.0,1.0, -8.0);
        glVertex3f( -1.0,0.0, -8.0);
        glVertex3f( 0.0,0.0, -8.0);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_OPENGL);

    int loop=1;
    SDL_Event myevent;
    init();
    while (loop==1)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&myevent))
        {
            switch(myevent.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                loop=0;
                break;


                if (myevent.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    px =px == -1 ? 1: px-1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    px=px ==1 ? -1 : px+1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    py = py == -1 ? 1 :py-1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    py = py == 1 ? -1 :py+1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        display();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not as you expected?

Comment: It cannot be used with arrow keys.

Comment: Please describe the behaviour you get and contrast it to the desired behaviour.

Comment: I am getting just 9 squares, the middle one is green (active) but, I cannot move to other squares with arrow keys.

Comment: Did you verify that any of the four relevant  `break;` is ever executed?

Comment: Yes but, still the same.

Comment: How did you verify? Debugger? Outputs? Did you e.g. output "left", "right", "up", "down" at the breaks and see that occur at the expected times? I.e. when you pressed the buttons?

Comment: I checked by Outputs :/

Comment: Please add that output code to the MRE and describe when they occurred.

Comment: I did it but I am getting no output :/

Comment: So what you are saying is that your MRE you show here (which by the way does NOT contain the debugging outputs we discuss) is not actually demonstrating the behaviour you observe. Time to double check and provide an actual [mre] of what you observe, including the debigging instrumentation needed for demonstrating what you observe. By the way, seeing the implausibilities called by Rabbid I doubted your MRE from square one....

Comment: What about the last `break;` - does it break switch-case or outer while-loop? I believe your program stuck in `while (SDL_PollEvent(&myevent))`